# How to check a boolean attribute in an if else statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model with a column superuser:boolean. I also using a navigationbar where I want to to have three different views according to those conditions:

- When someone is not signed in
- When someone is signed in as a user
- When someone is signed is as a user and the boolean value for superuser is true

  ```
  <% if (user_signed_in? && user.super_user?) %>

  <% elsif (user_signed_in?) %>

  <% else %>
  ```

I am getting the error: "undefined local variable or method `user'"

**How can I check if the column super_user of an user is true or false?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It looks like you're using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem (because of `user_signed_in?`). In this case it is a `current_user` helper you're looking for, not `user`.

2) You do not need `?` in here `current_user.super_user` - column is called `super_user`, not `super_user?`.

```
<% if (user_signed_in? && current_user.super_user) %>

<% elsif (user_signed_in?) %>

<% else %>
```

Comment: @trickydiddy no probs, don't forget to accept the answer if that did it for you (I know you can't yet for ~10 more mins) :)